# Any better way to print a checked checkBox in html?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

Assume that, I select a data from DB and the result is like this:

```
var dbObj = ["Z","E"];
```

Then I want to print 3 `CheckBox` , namely "Z", "N", "E"

Since the data from DB is ["Z" , "E"], the **check box Z** and **check box E** will be **checked** whereas **check box N** left to be **unchecked**. The result is like this:

[image: Result I want]

Here is my source code, you can copy it and play around:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>CheckBox</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var dbObj = [];
function validate(selection)
{
    switch(selection)
    {
        case 0:
        dbObj = ["Z",1,"E"];
        printZNECheckBox();
        break;
        case 1:
        dbObj = ["Z",1,2];
        printZNECheckBox();
        break;
        case 2:
        dbObj = ["Z","N","E"];
        printZNECheckBox();
        break;
        case 3:
        dbObj = [0, 1, "E"];
        printZNECheckBox();
        break;
    }
}

function printZNECheckBox()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < dbObj.length; i++)
    {
        if (typeof dbObj[i] == 'number')
        {
            printUnCheckedBox(dbObj[i]);
        }
        else {printCheckedBox(dbObj[i]);}
    }
}

function printCheckedBox(x)
{
    document.write("<input type =\"checkbox\" name=\"box\" id=\""+x+ "\" value=\""+x+"\" checked/>"+x);
}

function printUnCheckedBox(x)
{
    var str = "";
    switch (x)
    {
        case 0:
        str = "Z";
        break;
        case 1:
        str = "N";
        break;
        case 2:
        str = "E";
        break;
    }
    document.write("<input type =\"checkbox\" name=\"box\" id=\""+str+ "\" value=\""+str+"\"/>"+str);
}
</script>

<body>
    <input type="button" value="Data 1 from DB" onClick="validate(0)">
    <input type="button" value="Data 2 from DB" onClick="validate(1)">
    <input type="button" value="Data 3 from DB" onClick="validate(2)">
    <input type="button" value="Data 4 from DB" onClick="validate(3)">
</body>
</html>
```

Back to My Question:

**Is there any more direct way to acheive the same objective in JavaScript or Java?**

Comment: Java **is not** Javascript. Javascript is for client side while Java is for server side, and Java in web development has no idea about checkbox or other HTML components.

Comment: I am doing JSP. So I need to print the html components

Comment: JSP just means the server will use Java technology to dynamically add  HTML and/or another content like data got from a data source (database, file, etc) in the final HTML file. But the way your posted JSP code looks, this question is just HTML and JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's what you're looking for:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>CheckBox</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var dbObj = ["Z","N","E"];
var result = [];
function validate(selection)
{
    switch(selection)
    {
        case 0:
        result = ["Z","E"];
        printZNECheckBox();
        break;
        case 1:
        result = ["Z"];
        printZNECheckBox();
        break;
        case 2:
        result = ["Z","N","E"];
        printZNECheckBox();
        break;
        case 3:
        result = ["E"];
        printZNECheckBox();
        break;
    }
}

function printZNECheckBox()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < dbObj.length; i++)
    {
        printCheckedBox(dbObj[i]);
    }
}

function printCheckedBox(x)
{
    var isChecked = '';
    if(result.indexOf(x) != -1 ){ isChecked = "checked"; }
    document.write("<input type =\"checkbox\" name=\"box\" id=\""+x+ "\" value=\""+x+"\" "+isChecked+"/>"+x);
}

</script>

<body>
    <input type="button" value="Data 1 from DB" onClick="validate(0)">
    <input type="button" value="Data 2 from DB" onClick="validate(1)">
    <input type="button" value="Data 3 from DB" onClick="validate(2)">
    <input type="button" value="Data 4 from DB" onClick="validate(3)">
</body>
</html>
```